# Playing GIFs on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

How do I get GIFs to play on Windows Phone 8.1 apps? I see that the normal Image control simplay displays gifs as a static image.How would I go about actually playing the GIF in run-time like Internet Explorer does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [XamlAnimatedGif](https://github.com/XamlAnimatedGif/XamlAnimatedGif) to do this.

It is super easy to use. First you add the namespace to the Page tag:

```
xmlns:gif="using:XamlAnimatedGif"
```

Then show GIF's like this:

```
<Image gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="/Images/animated.gif" />
```

From the github page, it supports WPF, Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1 and Universal Windows Platform.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I think I must be screwing up somewhere.
`<Image x:Name="MyImage" gif:AnimationBehavior.SourceUri="{Binding uricheck}"  ></Image>`  . I manage to display the gif as a static image in a normal image control, but the Image gif: remains blank.

Comment: Take a look at the example app, and see what you're doing differently: https://github.com/thomaslevesque/XamlAnimatedGif/tree/master/TestApp.WinRT/TestApp.WinRT.WindowsPhone

Comment: Works wonderfully.Apologies for the confusion.I was reading a lot about WpfAnimatedGif so kept installing that package.XamlAnmiatedGif works!

Comment: Hi @Matt I'm trying to set a URL from a server, but it isnt working?

Comment: It is an excellent library. Thank you Thomas for sharing and Matt for letting us know. Yet Thomas is it possible for you to sign this library for nuget? We originally decided to use this library, yet after trying to push this to mobile devices we were stuck because it was not signed getting not strongly named errors. Even using 3rd party library like StrongNameSigner did not help this library for some reason and we had to remove it. Is it possible for you to sign?